# Magento Multiple Store not showing products on 1 out of 3 storefronts - tried the checklist.

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have a multiple magento store with 3 x storefronts. 2 are working fine, the other is not showing any products in categories.

I have done all the checklists, made sure they are in stock, allocated to the website, reindexed, to no avail. They show in the other storefronts correctly.

I have tried changing theme to a RWD but they still dont show. Imported currency as above.

disabled / re enabled product
out of stock / in stock
even checked database to make sure the product has the correct website id.

They show in the category admin page as being in that category.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated? 2 days now of clicking around and i'm going berserk.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the products are available, in stock, etc not only on default scope, but also on the store-view scope. 
Same with the category settings (display mode: products, static block, both) on default, but also on store-view scope.
Afterwards reindex and clear cache...

Do you use further cashing like Varnish or Redis? Vendor extensions which use other databases like Elastic or MongoDB for catalog pages?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have varnish but have bypassed this, turned it off and set httpd listening port back to 80.

Products are in stock and are marked for all stores. They are in categories on each of the stores root folder categories. 

In Manage Categories the category is displaying the product is assigned to it. Display mode is set to Static Block and Products. 


Reindex'ed deleted cache and var. Still nothing showing. 

Interesting enough I have just tried to add a new product to see if that would show and it is NOT showing in any stores at all.

Comment: another development is that by turning off Flat Catalog product indexing the back to eav, this has shown the product in 2 of the 3 multi stores. But I still need it on the 3rd.

Comment: Are your cronjobs (cron.sh) running?

Comment: Actually they are not - for some reason?????

Comment: Magento will automatically update indexes if everything is configured correctly and your cronjobs are running. See this documentation for more information: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/index-modes.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved by turning off Flat Catalog for both Product and Categories in
System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Product - NO
System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Category - NO

Then Forcing all indexes to reindex, even though they are green.

Interestingly turning flat catalog back on, the products show although newly added products do not and repeating the above is the only option.